# Add product in cart with name change programmatically in admin

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, adminhtml

I need to add a product in cart with a custom/dynamic name (that I will ask from user), I have tried this by changing product name to "Custom name" and then reverting to original after product is added in cart. But this isn't working, besides the custom product name gets saved in sales_flat_quote_item.

Is there something which I am missing, or if the method is not correct, please let me know the other one.

Answer (score 0):

i think you might have not saving the product after changing the name

```
$product->setName('custom-name');
$product->save();
```